# Codename One - Execute code only when the Internet connection is available

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to have a separate thread from the EDT, that is launched at app start and executes some code only when an Internet connection is available? I mean that it doesn't show or throw any error or exception if there a connection error, it has to wait until the connection to the server it's working.

My use case it's a version checking: compare the minimum supported app with the current app version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a separate thread to do this. You can just have a timer that polls your server. If there is no internet connection it can just fail silently. You can use `setFailSilently(true)` which swallows the errors from that specific URL.

Alternatively your global handling code can filter errors from that URL as the connection request is passed to the error event callback. E.g. this code starts a check 10 seconds after app launch so it won't slow down launch:

```
        UITimer.timer(10000, false, () -> {
           Server.checkVersion((currentVersion, oldestSupportedVersion) -> {
               float ver = Float.parseFloat(getProperty("AppVersion", "0.1"));
               if(ver < oldestSupportedVersion) {
                   Dialog.show("Error", "This version is out of date!\nPlease update the app from the store!", "Exit", null);
                   exitApplication();
                   return;
               }
               if(currentVersion > ver) {
                   ToastBar.showInfoMessage("A new version of the app is available...");
               }
           });
        });

public static interface VersionCallback {
    public void version(float currentVersion, float oldestSupportedVersion);
}

public static void checkVersion(VersionCallback ver) {
    Rest.
        get(url-to-properties-file-on-server).
        fetchAsBytes(res -> {
            if(res.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                try {
                    Properties p = new Properties();
                    p.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(res.getResponseData()));
                    String currentVer = p.getProperty("app.current","0.15");
                    String lastSupported = p.getProperty("app.lastSupported","0.14");
                    ver.version(Float.parseFloat(currentVer), 
                        Float.parseFloat(lastSupported));
                } catch(IOException err) {
                    Log.e(err);
                }
            }
        });
}
```